# std::get<0>(...) and enum index

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple

To make the code more readable I did the following with `tuple`:

```
std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t> key;

enum  tpl {
    arg1 = 0, arg2 = 1, arg3 = 2
};
```

Now I can write:

```
 auto _arg1 = std::get<tpl::arg1>(key);
```

I come to a problem now. If I write:

```
auto arg1 = std::get<tpl::arg1>(key);
```

The variable `arg1` is already the enum. Therefore I want to switch to:

```
enum class tpl: int {
    arg1 = 0, arg2 = 1, arg3 = 2
};
```

But something is wrong here. The compiler says:

> error C2672: 'std::get': no matching overloaded function found

What type is this index in `std::get` and can this be named at the definition of the enum class?

I tried

```
const constexpr
const int 
....
```

Comment: `The variable arg1 is already the enum` Not clear. Why is it the problem?

Comment: @balki - enumeration identifiers are members of the scope the `enum` is in (not `enum class`). So that can cause clashes unless one introduces some sort of scoping.

Comment: balki: The above names are only examples. In the real project there are several variables which has nearly the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A scoped enumeration (`enum class`) doesn't have an implicit conversion to integers of any sort. Since `std::get` expects a template parameter of an integral type, such a conversion must happen.

But it cannot, therefore no overload matches the supplied template argument.

You can use a "scoped enum" hack one resorted to prior to C++11:

```
struct tpl {
  enum : int {
    arg1 = 0, arg2 = 1, arg3 = 2
  };
};
```

This makes the identifiers scoped, but retains the implicit conversions. C++11 scoped enums were introduced because usually the implicit conversion is not a desired feature, but in this case I daresay it is.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that scoped enums aren't implicitly converted to their underlying type. You can manually do that by

```
std::get<static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<tpl>>(tpl::arg1)>(key);
```

but as your attempt is to increase the readability, this doesn't qualify as a good solution. Instead, consider this option:

```
namespace tpl {
   enum { arg1 = 0, arg2 = 1, arg3 = 2 };
}

std::get<tpl::arg1>(key);
```

It doesn't come with the same type safety implication as the strongly type enum, but it allows for the syntactic call you had in mind.

As a side note, once you are concerned about the readability implications of using `std::tuple` objects, you might want to switch to a trivial `struct` instead.

Comment: mmm... so `using namespace tpl;` allows for a shorthand when its possible. I like it, so have an uppy.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thx! Kind of a poor man's version of [P1099](https://atomgalaxy.github.io/using-enum/using-enum.html) :)

Comment: Yes, you are wright, I could switch to struct but tuples has some things in it. In the life-cycle of the project it can be that I switch. Thx for the soultion with namespace!

Answer (score 1):

[`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)'s index template parameter is of type `std::size_t`. A scoped enumeration is not implicitly convertible to its underlying type. So if you insist on using one, you must cast it.

```
auto arg1 = std::get<static_cast<int>(tpl::arg1)>(key);
```

If you want to avoid mentioning the underlying type in the cast

```
auto arg1 = std::get<static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<tpl>>(tpl::arg1)>(key);
```